# ASP.NET MVC Model binding from Querystring to Object and Request-response pattern

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

The model binding from **HTTP POST** params works great with the pattern Request-response, so i recieve in my controller the ViewModel that i need and i call the service layer with that object.
So everithing is encapsulated in the DTO ViewModel. If i want to add some other params i modify the object and not the method declaration.

I need to do the same thing if possible automatically with **HTTP GET** request (from QueryString)
so for example :

**/Index/CountryName/PageNumber/1** binding to controller **Index(string CountryName, int PageNumber)**

i want it to bind to this controller to : **Index(CountryQueryStringModel countryQueryStringModel)**

```
class CountryQueryStringModel 
{
   public string CountryName, 
   public int PageNumber 
}
```

With this approch, if i want to add for example a filter criteria i encapsulate it in the object `CountryQueryStringModel`

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you facing any issue? If you have set up the route properly the default model binder still bind the querystring values to the model right?

Comment: Ah ok you mean i can do it in the routing process ? how to the routing return the object to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

you are right Mark, the routing default model binder do it.
Here the solution i found

```
context.MapRoute(
                null,
                "hotel/{countryName}/Page/{pageNumber}",
                new { controller = "ResultsCity", action = "Index"},
                new[] { "California_Front.Areas.Hotel_FR.Controllers" }

context.MapRoute(
                null,
                "hotel/{countryName}/",
                new { controller = "ResultsCity", action = "Index", PageNumber = 1 },
                new[] { "California_Front.Areas.Hotel_FR.Controllers" }
```

the controller is like this

```
public ActionResult Index(CountryQueryStringModel CountryQueryStringModel)
{}
```

Thanks for help